# function is not null is not giving correct results on snowflake

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am doing a left join with 2 tables, and I get null values. I have a condition that says where datetime IS NOT NULL. However, when I run the query I still see null values.

Does anyone know how to fix this issue?

```
select 
*
from TBL_A A
LEFT JOIN 
(select 
    number_id, 
    country, 
    status, 
    number_of_days,
    datetime
FROM TBL_B) B 
    ON A.NUMBER_ID = B.NUMBER_ID
    AND A.STATUS = B.STATUS
    AND A.DATETIME < B.check_date
    AND B.datetime IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: You're doing a left join. While the join condition requires that you can't have a null datetime in the match that won't that doesn't mean you can't see nulls in the result. That's the whole point of the left join. Perhaps you mean `inner join`?

Answer (score 2):

> I have a condition that says where datetime IS NOT NULL

The condition is at `ON` level:

```
select *
from TBL_A A
LEFT JOIN (select number_id,  country, status, number_of_days, datetime
           FROM TBL_B) B 
    ON A.NUMBER_ID = B.NUMBER_ID
    AND A.STATUS = B.STATUS
    AND A.DATETIME < B.check_date
    AND B.datetime IS NOT NULL  -- here
```

In order filter out `NULLS` it should be at `WHERE` level:

```
select *
from TBL_A A
LEFT JOIN (select number_id,  country, status, number_of_days, datetime
           FROM TBL_B) B 
    ON A.NUMBER_ID = B.NUMBER_ID
    AND A.STATUS = B.STATUS
    AND A.DATETIME < B.check_date
WHERE B.datetime IS NOT NULL
```

But at this moment it is not different that `INNER JOIN`:

```
select *
from TBL_A A
JOIN (select number_id,  country, status, number_of_days, datetime
           FROM TBL_B) B 
    ON A.NUMBER_ID = B.NUMBER_ID
    AND A.STATUS = B.STATUS
    AND A.DATETIME < B.check_date
    AND B.datetime IS NOT NULL  -- here
```

Answer (score 0):

Can't you filter on the query like below, before using the `JOIN`?

```
 select 
        number_id, 
        country, 
        status, 
        number_of_days,
        datetime
    FROM TBL_B where datetime is not null
```

Comment: Thanks Jeremy for editing ..